# Vscode "Unable to open [file]: Unable to read file" message when clicking on an error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, path, linter

I get this message when I click on a warning. This is a screenshot of the case.
[image]

The error reads,

> Unable to open 'warning.cpp': Unable to read file
>   '`/Users/dimen/code/C++/Users/dimen/code/C++/warning.cpp`'
>   (Error: Unable to resolve non-existing file
>   '`/Users/dimen/code/C++/Users/dimen/code/C++/warning.cpp`').

My script is located in  `/Users/dimen/code/C++/warning.cpp` so vscode reiterates the path for some reason.

I suspected that the linter setting must've been written erroneously but I'm not sure where I should edit. As some side notes,

- Using Microsoft's C/C++ extension.
- `tasks.json` have been customized so that all the builds go inside the `build` folder

Comment: Did you ever fix this? I have the same problem

Comment: I have the same problem. I don't know how fix it

Comment: I am also looking for a fix for this. All I did was rename a directory and now this is all I ever get in vscode.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was facing this issue also.

For resolving this issue, I closed the VSCode and again imported **folder again as Path of folder got changed** in mine conditions.

If this doesn't work, you can uninstall VSCode and then reinstall it.

Answer (score 4):

You need to edit the `problemMatcher` part of `tasks.json` so that it has a variable called `fileLocation` that is set to `absolute`. Here is an example of what it should look like:

```
"problemMatcher": {
    "base" : "$gcc",
    "fileLocation" : "absolute"
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Check [this link](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/4975). It seems to require detailed configurations for the directory. In `task.json` the `problemMatcher` takes the file directory as relative so you got repeating path. Setting `"fileLocation"` to `"absolute"` works on my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked in tasks.json:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            //"type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "build my project",
            "command": "/home/user/path/build.bash",
            "args": [
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": {
                "base": "$gcc",
                "fileLocation": "absolute",
            },
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

For some reason i had to specifically remove "type": "cppbuild" for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by making a change in 'launch.json' file. I changed the value of "cwd" below "name": "(gdb) Launch eds" in "configurations" field. I set it to the absolute path of the folder containing the project. Below is my launch.json file. I'm using VS Code on Ubuntu.

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch eds",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/build_x86_debug/bin/fcc",
            "args": ["-a=${workspaceFolder}/build_x86_debug/bin/", "-d=${workspaceFolder}/build_x86_debug/bin/", "-c=${workspaceFolder}/build_x86_debug/bin/"],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "/home/aiden/dev2",
            "environment": [{"name": "LD_LIBRARY_PATH", "value": "/usr/lib:${workspaceFolder}/build_x86_debug/bin:${workspaceFolder}/pocolib1.7.5"}],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch",
            "type": "lldb",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/build_x86/bin/emvadapter",
            "cwd" : "/home/vendor",
            "env" : { "LD_LIBRARY_PATH":"/home/vendor/lib" }

        },
        {
            "name": "Unit Tests",
            "type": "lldb",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/build_x86/bin/",
            "linux": { "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/vendor"}
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29817520)

Answer (score 0):

I got this too on [ApiLogicServer](https://github.com/valhuber/ApiLogicServer/blob/main/README.md), which uses this feature extensively.

Took a few, but this resolved it by clicking container (lower left) and then rebuild-container:

[image]